# jQuery and $.post

Tags: jquery, json, post

I am using that:

```
 $.post("src/php/login.php",{
    "user" : {
        "username" : $("#login").val(),
        "password" : $("#pass").val(),
    }
 }, function ( response ) {
    alert(response);
    $("#but").removeAttr("disabled");
 });
```

And how I can get this json object at php:

```
 $q = json_decode($_POST[?]);
```

What I have to set of '?' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do `$_POST['user']` on the PHP side. And you don't have to do a json_decode, because it will be posted as an array with this structure. e.g.:

```
$_POST['user']['username']
$_POST['user']['password']`
```

Comment: That should be $_POST['user']['username'] and $_POST['user']['password'] (singular 'user').

Answer (score 1):

`user` will work:

```
$_POST["user"];
```